# How to create folder structure in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 using Core Service

Tags: c#, tridion

I am using the Core Service on Tridion 2011. I want to create a folder structure, and then create a component in that structure.

Example: 
Path of folder structure: /ABCD/DEFG/aaaaa

If the folder exists, we need not create folder. If it doesn't exist we have to create it and create component in it.

I know how to create the component in a folder having URI.

Comment: @Muzimil - you may want to consider committing to the Tridion SE site - A lot of these question would be appropriate there: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is the code I use when I need to Get or Create Folders with SDL Tridion's CoreService. It's a simple recursive method that checks for the existence of the current folder. If it doesn't exist, it goes into GetOrCreate the parent folder and so on until it finds an existing path. On the way out of the recursion, it simply creates the new Folders relative to their immediate parent.

**Note**: this method does not check the input `folderPath`. Rather, it assumes it represents a valid path.

```
private FolderData GetOrCreateFolder(string folderPath, SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client)
{
    ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();

    if (client.IsExistingObject(folderPath))
    {
        return client.Read(folderPath, readOptions) as FolderData;
    }
    else
    {
        int lastSlashIdx = folderPath.LastIndexOf("/");
        string newFolder = folderPath.Substring(lastSlashIdx + 1);
        string parentFolder = folderPath.Substring(0, lastSlashIdx);
        FolderData parentFolderData = GetOrCreateFolder(parentFolder, client);
        FolderData newFolderData = client.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Folder, parentFolderData.Id) as FolderData;
        newFolderData.Title = newFolder;

        return client.Save(newFolderData, readOptions) as FolderData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use IsExistingObject - passing in the WebDAV URL - to see if the Folder already exists. If it returns false, you can go ahead and create the folder.

**Edit:** Here's some quick pseudo code...

```
string parentFolderId = @"/webdav/MyPublication/Building%20Blocks";

var client = GetCoreServiceClient();

if (!client.IsExistingObject(parentFolderId + "/AAA"))
{
   var folder = client.GetDefaultData(2, parentFolderId);
   folder.Title = "AAA";
   client.Save(folder);
   // Create the other folders and components here
}
```

Comment: can you please share the complete name of the class and share how to create a folder.

Comment: It's a method on the Core Service client. Anyway, I added some quick example code from memory. Hopefully that's enough to get you going.

Answer (score 3):

This is what we used on one of our projects to create folders for a path.

```
static FolderData GetOrCreateFolder(List<string> folders, 
                                    FolderData root,
                                    SessionAwareCoreService2010Client client)
{
    var filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
    filter.ItemTypes = new [] { ItemType.Folder };

    var items = client.GetListXml(root.Id, filter).
                           Elements(TRIDION_NAMESPACE + "Item");

    foreach (var element in items)
    {
        if (folders.Count == 0)
        {
            break; // break from foreach
        }
        var titleAttribute = element.Attribute("Title");
        var idAttribute = element.Attribute("ID");
        if (titleAttribute != null && titleAttribute.Value == folders[0] && 
            idAttribute != null)
        {
            // folder exists
            FolderData fd = client.Read(idAttribute.Value, 
                                        EXPANDED_READ_OPTIONS) as FolderData;

            // We just took care of this guy, remove it to recurse
            folders.RemoveAt(0);

            return GetOrCreateFolder(folders, fd, client);
        }
    }

    if (folders.Count != 0)
    {
        //Folder doesn't exist, lets create it and return its folderdata
        var newfolder = new FolderData();
        newfolder.Title = folders[0];
        newfolder.LocationInfo = new LocationInfo { 
            OrganizationalItem = new LinkToOrganizationalItemData { 
                IdRef = root.Id 
            }
        };
        newfolder.Id = "tcm:0-0-0";

        var folder = client.Create(newfolder, EXPANDED_READ_OPTIONS) 
                               as FolderData;

        folders.RemoveAt(0);

        if (folders.Count > 0)
        {
            folder = GetOrCreateFolder(folders, folder, client);
        }
        return folder;
    }
    return root;
}
```

So you'd invoke it with something like this:

```
var root = client.Read("tcm:1-1-2", null) as FolderData;
var pathParts = "/ABCD/DEFG/aaaaa".Trim('/').Split('/').ToList();
var folder = GetOrCreateFolder(pathParts, root, client);
```

Comment: @Frank.Thank you for the answer. It would be a pleasure if you can share me how to create folder structure. Example:/webdav/MyPublication/Building%20Blocks/Folder1/Folder2 I have to search for the given path, if given path doesnot exists, then i have to create a folder structure.Even if "Folder1" doesnot exist i need to create it.I have to rely upon the path only.

Comment: That is EXACTLY what this code does. I now added an example of how to invoke the method. If you have problems getting it to work, please share the code that you wrote and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I have some doubts in the code. 
1.Is the root in the invoke process indicates name of publication/root folder under which we want to create folders.
2.As we are using  folders.RemoveAt(0) method, if the folder in the path exists, does it return the folder data. Because we are already removing it.
Please share your response on this.
Thank you

Comment: 1. root is type `FolderData` which he gets by tcm id from the client object and 2. Yes, the code returns and uses (yay, recursion) the `folder` data. `RemoveAt(0)` simply removes the first item in the `folders` array and reduces its count by one. Use a Pez dispenser for an illustration or look into the idea of a "stack."

Answer (score 2):

For Create a folder use the following code as sample...
You will have to check if the folder exists of course, this code shows how to create a folder within a folder

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CoreWebService.ServiceReference1;

namespace CoreWebService
{
    class CoreWebServiceSamples
    {

        public static void createFolder()
        {
            string folderWebDavUrl = "/webdav/020%20Content/Building%20Blocks/Content/wstest";

            CoreServicesUtil coreServicesUtil = new CoreServicesUtil();

            FolderData folderData = coreServicesUtil.getFolderData(folderWebDavUrl);


            FolderData folderDataChild = folderData.AddFolderData();
            folderDataChild.Title = "childFolder";

            folderDataChild = (FolderData)coreServicesUtil.coreServiceClient.Save(folderDataChild, coreServicesUtil.readOptions);
            coreServicesUtil.coreServiceClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some code for the methods referenced ....
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using CoreWebService.ServiceReference1;
    using CoreWebService.Properties;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

```
namespace CoreWebService
{

    public class CoreServicesUtil
    { 
        public CoreService2010Client coreServiceClient;
        public ReadOptions readOptions;
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public CoreServicesUtil()
        {
            this.coreServiceClient = new CoreService2010Client("basicHttp_2010");
            this.readOptions = new ReadOptions();
        }


        public  FolderData getFolderData(string tcmuri)
        {
            FolderData folderData = (FolderData)coreServiceClient.Read(tcmuri, readOptions);
            return folderData;
        }


    }

    public static class CoreServicesItemCreator
    {

        /**
        * <summary>
        * Name: AddFolder
        * Description: returns a new Folder Data created in the folder Data
        * </summary>
        **/
        public static FolderData AddFolderData(this FolderData folderData)
        {
            FolderData childFolder = new FolderData();
            childFolder.LocationInfo = getLocationInfo(folderData);
            childFolder.Id = "tcm:0-0-0";
            return childFolder;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the review Frank, appreciated